# Excel: Referencing different workbook name always auto completes to full path when using in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am referencing a different workbook in my worksheet. This file needs to be used by multiple users who would have the referenced workbook open for the data to update.

In other sheets created by a different user, other workbooks are referenced simply by using (for example) `'[Workbookname.xlsx]Sheet0'!$AA12` while my system always auto-completes this type of input into a full path name e.g. `'C:\\User\Reports\[Workbookname.xlsx]Sheet0'!$AA12` disabling other users to use this worksheet because of the different folder structures.

Is there a way to keep the reference without the full path so users with different folder structures can use this too while having the referenced workbook open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are getting wrong how Excel works.

Say you have workbooks `dir1\base.xlsx` and `dir1\ref.xlsx` open.
Now in cell `[base.xlsx]Sheet1!A1` you add the formula `=[ref.xlsx]Sheet1!A1`, and that is what you see as the formula.

If you close `dir1\ref.xlsx`, the displayed formula will now include the full path.
But whether Excel shows the full path or not (in case the referenced file is closed or open) is a "courtesy" from Excel to you, to make your life easier. 
Cell `[base.xlsx]Sheet1!A1` will always refer to cell `Sheet1!A1` in file `dir1\ref.xlsx`.

If you now open in Excel another file named `ref.xlsx` from a different directory, cell `[base.xlsx]Sheet1!A1` will still refer to cell `Sheet1!A1` in file `dir1\ref.xlsx`, and the formula in that cell will still show the full path, since the referenced workbook is closed.

I just tested all this to confirm.

As for the possibility of referencing external workbooks with relative paths, the information I found is not consistent.
I have just tested a few combinations, and I found Excel always stores absolute paths in references to external workbooks. So what you mean to do would not work out-of-the box.

OTOH, [official documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/328440/description-of-link-management-and-storage-in-excel) states

> **Relative vs. absolute links**
>
> Links to external workbooks are created in
>   a relative manner *whenever possible*. This means that the full path to
>   the source data file is not recorded, but rather the portion of the
>   path as it relates to the linked workbook. With this method, you can
>   move the workbooks without breaking the links between them. The links
>   remain intact, however, only if the workbooks remain in the same
>   location relative to each other. For example, if the linked file is
>   C:\Mydir\Linked.xls and the source data file is
>   C:\Mydir\Files\Source.xls, you can move the files to the D drive as
>   long as the source file is still located in a subfolder called
>   "files".
>
> Relative links may cause problems if you move the linked file to
>   different computers and the source is in a central location.

so relative paths would be possible. "Whenever possible" (sic) seems a light specification to me, and you may explore this a little further. The example provided in the text above may help in understanding.

But in [this thread](http://www.actuarialoutpost.com/actuarial_discussion_forum/showthread.php?t=257933) the asker complains about Excel using relative paths, while he actually wants absolute referencing.

And [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11631321/2707864) found VBA as the only way to have relative paths.
There are also other solutions there.

An alternative is [to use `INDIRECT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22149831/2707864). That is guaranteed to work, but writing formulas is cumbersome, and it may have performance issues. I would only use it if having just a few formulas needing it.

So I guess this point is not very clear to me, but the references provided should help you.

**If you find the way to do it, I welcome you posting it for the benefit of the SO community.**